# Wrap std::vector class to make queries look like .net List<T> queries

Tags: c++

When i switched to c++ from c#, one of the most missed functionalities was the List class queries like - find, findall, exists, etc., combined with lambda predicates.

So, i decided to wrap the vector class and enjoy the "syntactic sugar" of the result.

I'm aware that not all vector members are rewritten and this can serve just as example of my idea.

The question is:

Is this a viable solution of my problem?

Are there conceptual mistakes that would ruin performance or the behavior of the wrapped class?

Here the wrapper looks like:

```
 #include<vector>

template<typename T>
class VectorWrap
{
public:
    std::vector<T> v;

    VectorWrap() noexcept:v{} {}
    VectorWrap(std::initializer_list<T> list)noexcept : v{ list } {}

    T& operator[](int i) noexcept { return v[i]; }
    const T& operator[](int i) const noexcept { return v[i]; }

    void add(const T& a) noexcept { v.push_back(a); }
    void push_back(const T& a) noexcept { v.push_back(a); }

    void clear() noexcept { v.clear(); }
    const auto size() const noexcept { return v.size(); }
    const auto begin() const noexcept { return v.begin(); }
    const auto end() const noexcept { return v.end(); }
    const bool empty() const noexcept { return v.empty(); }

    bool contains(const T& a) const noexcept
    {
        auto x = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), a);
        return x != std::end(v);
    }

    template<typename Pred>
    T find(Pred p) const noexcept
    {
        auto x = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), p);
        return x != std::end(v) ? *x : T{};
    }

    template<typename Pred>
    bool any(Pred p) const noexcept
    {
        return std::any_of(std::begin(v), std::end(v), p);
    }

    template<typename Pred>
    VectorWrap<T> findall(Pred p) noexcept
    {
        VectorWrap res;
        for (auto* x : v)
            if (p(x)) res.push_back(x);
        return res;
    }

    template<typename Pred>
    const T& minby(Pred p) const noexcept
    {
        if (v.size() == 0)
            return T{};
        return *std::min_element(v.begin(), v.end(), p);
    }

    template<typename Pred>
    const T& maxby(Pred p) const noexcept
    {
        if (v.size() == 0)
            return T{};
        return *std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end(), p);
    }
};
```

Edit:

For all those in the comments that seems like didn't catch the idea behind my question.

I don't claim to completely replace any container class. I just made an example for few functionalities of the vector that i use a lot. For the same purpose i made the underlying vector public.

But that's not the point. The real point was the "syntactic sugar" behind. The possibility to type:

```
VectorWrap<int> MyWrappedExampleVectorInstance = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

int result = MyWrappedExampleVectorInstance.find([&](int i) { return i > 1 && i < 5; });
```

instead of:

```
std::vector<int> MyNonWrappedExampleVectorInstance = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<int>>> firstMatchOnLambdaPredicate = std::find_if(MyNonWrappedExampleVectorInstance.begin(), MyNonWrappedExampleVectorInstance.end(), [&](int i) { return i > 1 && i < 5; });

int result = *firstMatchOnLambdaPredicate;
```

I hope that you can see the difference of the readability and the conciseness between both examples.

Comment: Returning `T{}` from a function that has a `const T&` return type is not going to end well. That temporary object will cease to exist by the time anyone can use that reference. A `const T&` *can* extend the lifetime of a temporary `T`, but not in this context.

Comment: Do you really need them as member functions?  All this functionality already exits in the [algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) library and [range v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3)

Comment: And when you decide to change to `std::deque`, do you write another interface?

Comment: What you gain with this class (new names for common idioms) will likely be outweighed by what you lose ([many features of vector that you have not implemented](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)).  You can solve this by writing a collection of free functions that act on `std::vector` instead of writing a replacement for `std::vector`.

Comment: You forgot the plethora of other algorithm functions, plus `const` and reverse iterators. -- *When i switched to c++ from c#,* -- Don't use other languages as models in writing proper C++ code.

Comment: Have you looked at [algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) *at all*?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie 'Don't use other languages as models in writing **improper**..' - fixed for you.

Comment: @François Andrieux: Thank you for the only one constructive comment around here. Do you have an idea how to return the appropriate default value type that will last long enough?

Comment: Given your edit: Please use `auto`.  It's a safe assumption that a reader would know what type `std::find_if` is returning.  You'll probably discover that your code is more readable if you're the author of `VectorWrap` and less readable if you're not.  But that's a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Drew Dormann : _--You'll probably discover that your code is more readable if you're the author of VectorWrap and less readable if you're not. But that's a matter of opinion.--_. I totally agree. I didn't use auto on purpose in order to emphasize the gibberish look of the second example.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ ideology, a great emphasis is put on the separation between data and algorithm. This is why `vector` doesn't have the `find` method - the simple sequential search works same way for vectors, lists and queues.

Because of that, there is no need to duplicate the sequential search logic in all those containers - instead, a sequential search `find` function is written once (called algorithm) and made in a such way that it is independent of any container which is capable of sequence iteration. This provides for a plethora of benefits - no need to repeat the same code in multiple containers, if improvement is made in the algorithm, it automatically becomes available to all containers and the rest of benefits which are usually associated with avoidance of code duplication.

This doesn't work always like that - for example, associative containers (sets, maps) do have a method `find` defined on them, since their search operations are not sequential lookups and require knowledge of data representation to be efficient.

The one thing I personally do not like about STL algos is that they historically take a pair of iterators, and it is too easy to make a mistake by providing a pair of unrelated iterators.  But this is solved with Ranges.

Comment: Thank you for your ideology. I edited my question to make it more comprehensive for some of our audience here.